# Guest User with Object access restriction able to retrieve data from List View with sharing 'Visible to All Users'?

Tags: sharing, customer-community, list-view, guest-user

**Issue:** We observed during a recent scan of our Customer Community that data for a custom object could be retrieved (via API GET) from the List View even though Guest User has no access to the object. Please see below for our current setup -

**Setup Is Below**:

- Custom object exposed on the Customer Community
- Guest Profile has 'No Access' to the custom object.
- Guest User is not the Owner of any records for the custom object
- OWD for the object is 'Public Read Only' (since we want Customer Community users to be able to see records submitted by everyone).
- There are no Sharing Rules defined for the custom object.
- List View for this custom object sits on a page with 'Requires Authorization for Access'
- List View sharing is 'Visible to All Users' (since there is no specific way to share all records with Customer Community users - [idea is suggested](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWTIUA3/allow-sharing-list-view-for-customer-community-login-license))

**NOTE** - We did observe that the data becomes unavailable to the Guest User (via API GET retrieval) upon changing the List View sharing to a 'Public Group' (for example, All Customer Portal Users). However the 'All Customer Portal Users' does not work for 'High Volume Users' and we want the records to be visible to all Customer Community license users.

Any thoughts on how this dilemma can be prevented OR suggestions to check something in our Security/Sharing setup? Same question asked on the [Trailblazer Community](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000G2rjASAR) for any insights. Thanks!